# git svn create a new svn branch based on a git branch

Tags: git, git-svn, branching-and-merging

Is it possible to create an svn branch off of a git branch? That is, I currently interact with an svn repository using git-svn. I've created a new git branch into which I've merged some new changes. Now I want to push this branch to the svn repository, albeit into it's own svn branch so others may download this. Plus I'd like to keep tracking that branch via my git branch.

Is this possible? I tried git svn branch, but it creates the branch off of the master, not my off of my branch...

thanks to all!
Rodrigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried git svn branch, but it creates the branch off of the master, not my off of my branch

That is actually correct. Svn should have something to base your new branch upon. You should rebase your git-only changes onto that svn/newBranch and then dcommit it. Before doing dcommit you might check that you are pushing to the right svn branch by looking at the output of `git svn info`.

If you want your svn branch to be based on some other svn branch rather than master(trunk), you should check it out first (do `git svn info` again to check it all good) and do `git svn branch` from there.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I did, and worked as you mentioned (and as I wanted).